# Is it possible to find out TTFB with Scrapy + Splash?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I can find out the page load time with Scrapy + Splash but is it possible to get the Time To First Byte (like on Chrome's network tab)?

I want to measure how fast the server rendered the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:

```
local entries = splash:history()
local last_response = entries[#entries].response
last_response.timings.wait
```